# Get changes associated with a build in Azure Devops using REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops

In Azure Devops under the "Summary" tab associated with a build, there are a list of changes (Git hashes, etc.) associated with the build.  I'm trying to figure out how to get these via the rest API.

I found [this REST API to get the changes between the two builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

It works if I have the previous build id in the pipeline, however in the situation I'm interested in, I have the current build id, I need to somehow use the REST API to find the previous id.

Is there a way to do this using the REST API, or a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, there's a [special REST API call for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). You pass the `buildId` as a part of the URL and get the collection of changes (`Change[]`) in response.

Comment: Worked perfectly